# Проблема с последовательностью листнеров

Tags: javascript, node.js, telegram-bot

Есть тг бот. Есть листнер на степ регестрацию. И его нужно останавливать при одном сообщении.

код который должен останавливать выглядит так:

```
bot.onText(/ Скасувати запис/, async (msg) => {
    const chatId = msg.chat.id
    const user = users[chatId]
    try {
        if (await user.get("action") == "consultation") {
            await bot.sendMessage(chatId, ' Запис на консультацію була скасована');
            await delete users[chatId];
        }
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
    }
})
```

и после этого листнера идет **второй** тот который должен остановиться:

```
bot.on("message", (m) => {...})
```

но второй листнер все равно успевает выполнится до того как данные, которые проверяются на наличие в втором листнере, удаляются.

и есть **третий** листнер:

```
bot.onText(/\/consultation/, (msg) => {...})
```

этот листнер дает возможность **второму** начинать степ регестрацию

Как решить данную проблему?

Comment: что за объект users?

Comment: @Grundy в users записываются все юзеры которые проходят степ регистрацию, и в значениях записывается информация полученая при регистрации

Comment: где и как объявлена эта переменная? Какой тип у этой переменной?

Comment: `await delete` - бесполезная запись - потому что `delete` выполняется синхронно

Comment: как выглядит текст сообщения, который вы пытаетесь обработать?

Comment: Используйте [Scene](https://github.com/telegraf/telegraf/issues/705) для создания последовательных форм из которых можно легко выйти или войти

Comment: @Grundy users - объект который был объявлен в начале, user - создавал при команде "/consultation" через Map(). И я немного напутал с листнерами, на команду "/consultation" конкретно задается user что он у него есть регестрация. Вопрос поправил и добавил нужный код

Comment: что значит "остановить листенер"? Ты хочешь чтобы обработчик не выполнялся? Не выполнялся только для конкретного юзера или вообще для всех?